# How to approach multiple async calls on single array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

this is bit more theoretical question. I originally intented to call this question *Is it possible to iterate over map twice*, but just from the sound of it, it sounds like an anti-pattern. So I assume I'm just approaching this wrong.

> *Also note: Data here servers as an abstraction. I know that what I'm doing here with data provided here is unnecessary, but **please don't get fixated too much on data-structure** and what-not. It does not represent the real (more complex, which furthermore is provided by client and I can't alter) data I'm working with. Instead approach the problem as **how to return structured async calls for each array item** please! :-)*

---

My problem boils down to this:

- I have array of `id`s on which I need to execture two separate asynchronous calls
- Both of these callls need to pass (and in all `id` instances)

So as an example, imagine I have these two data-sets:

```
const dataMessages = [
  { id: "a", value: "hello" }, 
  { id: "b", value: "world" }
];

const dataNames = [
  { id: "a", name: "Samuel" },
  { id: "b", name: "John" },
  { id: "c", name: "Gustav"},
];
```

And an API-call mock-up:

```
const fetchFor = async (collection: Object[], id: string): Promise<Object> => {
  const user = collection.find(user => user.id === id);
  if (!user) {
    throw Error(`User ${id} not found`);
  }
  return user;
};
```

Now **I need to call the `fetchFor()` function for both the data-sets**, presumably inside the inside the `Promise.all`, given `forEach` is not asynchronous from a predetermined array of `id`s.

I was thinking something akin to `map`ing a list of Promises for the `Promise.all` to execute. This works fine, when you only need to map a single api-call:

```
const run = async () => {
  const result = await Promise.all(
    ['a', 'b'].map(id => fetchFor(dataMessages, id)
  )
  console.log(result) // [{id: 'a', value: 'hello'}, {id: 'b', value: 'world}]
}
```

However I somehow need to return both promises for the

- `fetchFor(dataMessages, id)`
- `fetchFor(dataNames, id)`

inside the `Promise.all` array of Promises.

---

> I guess I could always simply do a `flatMap` of two maps for both instances of API calls, but that sounds kinda dumb, given
>
> - I'd be doing array.map on same array twice
> - My data structure would not be logically connected *(two separate array items for the same user, which would not even by followed by eachother)*

So ideally I'd like to return dat in form of

```
 const result = await Promise.all([...])
 console.log(result)
 /* [
 *   {id: 'a', message: 'hello', name: 'Samuel'},
 *   {id: 'b', message: 'world', name: 'John'},
 *  ]
```

Or do I simply have to do flatmap of promises and then do data-merging to objects based on id identifier inside a separate handler on the resolved Promise.all?

I've provided a working example of the single-api-call mockup here, so you don't have to copy-paste.

[image: Edit zen-wildflower-480ig]

What would be the correct / common way of approaching such an issue?

Comment: Why would you need to call `fetchFor(dataMessages, id)`? Don't you just need to add the messages for `id` to the `user` (if there's one)?

Comment: @Andreas No. I know in the example it would make sense, but instead of messages / id please think of these as data fields inside an actual database (and obviously in reality I'm returning more than one field). I just chose those two things as an **abstraction of the issue**, as an representation of (much more complex) thing I have to do. Question is about **returning two structured Promises inside a single map**, so don't get fixated too much on the correctness of data-structure and what-not please :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could nest `Promise.all` calls:

```
const [messages, names] = await Promise.all([
  Promise.all(
    ['a', 'b'].map(id => fetchFor(dataMessages, id)
  ),
  Promise.all(
    ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(id => fetchFor(dataNames, id)
  )
]);
```

If you're wanting to then merge the results after retrieved, it's just a matter of standard data manipulation.

Comment: Oh yeah, now that I look back at it, i'm kinda baffled how it didn't occur to me to simply think of `Promise.all` as to two Promises which can be elements for argument array of another `Promise.all`, neat :-) !

Comment: One last thing, after bit of my own research, I've found you can also use `for of` with two async calls, but if I understand correctly, `Promise.all` approach is better, since it can run concurrently, hence faster with large set of data, right?